# Signed minimum?

Tags: tag-removed, computer-science

I am looking for references to papers which might have defined a 'signed minimum' equivalent to
$$smin(x,y) ::= \left(\frac{\textit{signum}(x)+\textit{signum}(y)}{2}\right)\cdot \min(|x|,|y|) $$
where $\textit(signum)(x)$ is $-1$ for $x\lt 0$, $1$ for $x\gt 0$ and an arbitrary (finite) value for $x=0$.  Also, any simpler expression for $smin$ would be appreciated.  The above definition works for $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{Q}$, and $\mathbb{Z}$.

Intuition: the 'signed minimum' between x and y is the one closest to $0$ if they both have the same sign, otherwise it's 0.

Comment: Why doesn't this work for $\mathbb{Z}$?  You can just do case-by case analysis and verify that the result always going to be an integer.

Comment: It does work, I guess my phrasing is a tad awkward.

Answer (score 3):

$smin(x,y)$ can also be described as the number of smallest absolute value in the closed interval between $x$ and $y$.

When $x \le y$ are integers, this is also the value of the game $\{x-1 \mid y+1\}$ in the sense of combinatorial game theory (Conway, *On Numbers And Games*).